# How to get a partition from an irrep of Sn

Tags: representation-theory

I'm aware of the fact that the (finite dimensional and over complex numbers) irreducible representations (which I will shorten to irreps) of $S_n$ (up to isomorphism) are in bijection with partitions $\lambda$ of $n$.

However, I feel like the bijection is a bit one-sided. Here is my understanding of how I have seen the result (you can probably skip over this info if you just want to answer my question, stated at the end of this two paragraph spiel):

For instance, we prove that the number of irreps = the number of conjugacy classes via arguments of orthogonality of characters. In the case of $S_n$, the number of conjugacy classes happens to be the number of partitions of $n$, because of cycle decompositions.

Then, one shows that to each partition $\lambda$ of $n$, one can construct an irrep $V_\lambda$ of $S_n$, and they are pairwise non-isomorphic. Since you get the correct number of irreps, you must have found them all. This establishes a bijection.

All of this to say: given an irrep of $S_n$, by which I mean some explicit homomorphism $\rho: S_n \to GL(V)$, how does one determine the partition $\lambda$ for which $V_\lambda$ and $V$ are isomorphic?

Now, I am pretty sure you can just use characters. However, I would like to know if there is some other approach, more akin to the highest weight approach to irreps of Lie algebras.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at Vershik-Okounkov's "A New Approach to the Representation Theory of the Symmetric group" ([arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503040.pdf), [journal version](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10958-005-0421-7))

Comment: One approach using [Young tableaux](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Young_symmetrizer) produces [Specht modules](https://yufeizhao.com/research/youngtab-hcmr.pdf) for each partition $\lambda \vdash n$.

Comment: @Sammy: that goes in the opposite direction from what the OP is asking about.

Comment: D'oh. You are correct, @QiaochuYuan :-P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a direct description, which has been known for a very long time (at least since the work of Jucys and Murphy; you can find a summary in the paper of Okounkov and Vershik mentioned in the comments to the question).

For $1 \leq j \leq n$ let
$$\psi_j=\sum_{1 \leq k < \ell \leq j} (k\ell)$$ be the sum of all the transpositions in the group algebra $\mathbf{C} S_j$ of the symmetric group $S_j$ and let
$$\phi_j=\sum_{1 \leq k < j} (kj)=\psi_j-\psi_{j-1}.$$

Since $\psi_j$ is central in $\mathbf{C} S_j$, it follows that the various $0=\phi_1,\phi_2,\dots,\phi_n$ commute with one another in the group algebra $\mathbf{C} S_n$. Moreover they are self-adjoint as operators on any irreducible $\mathbf{C} S_n$-module equipped with a positive definite $S_n$-invariant Hermitian form; thus they may be simultaneously diagonalized. It is a fact that these eigenvalues determine the partition you are after.

More precisely, here is the theorem: let $M$ be an irreducible $\mathbf{C} S_n$-module and let $v \in M$ be a simultaneous eigenvector for $\phi_1,\phi_2,\dots,\phi_n$, with eigenvalues given by
$$\phi_i v=c_i v \quad \hbox{for $c_i \in \mathbf{C}$.}$$ Then there is a unique partition $\lambda$ whose multi-set of *contents* is the set $\{c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n\}$, where we visualize partitions as consisting of collections of boxes via their Young diagrams, and where the *content* of a box is $a-b$ if it is in column $a$ and row $b$.

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer but a bit too long to be a comment. Given an irrep $W$ of $S_n$ we can consider, for an auxiliary vector space $V$, the tensor product

$$F_W(V) = V^{\otimes n} \otimes_{S_n} W.$$

This is the [Schur functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_functor) associated to $W$, and it is naturally an irreducible representation of $GL(V)$ by [Schur-Weyl duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality) (at least over a field of characteristic zero). The two most familiar examples are if $W$ is the trivial resp. the sign representation, in which case the corresponding Schur functors are the symmetric power $S^n(V)$ resp. the exterior power $\Lambda^n(V)$.

The Schur functors are known to have characters as representations of $GL(V)$ which, when expressed in terms of the eigenvalues, are symmetric functions known as the [Schur functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial). These are indexed by partitions. So your question can be reduced to recognizing which partition corresponds to a given Schur function (once you believe that this bijection between irreducibles and partitions is the same as the one coming from e.g. Specht modules, which is also not obvious and needs to be proven). I think there should be some highest weight stuff you can do here but I am not familiar enough with the details to say exactly what the recipe is.